# Login using single sign on (SSO) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, single-sign-on

I plan to introduce a [single sign-on (SSO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) to my Laravel 5 applications. Basically, I have two websites on different domains. The idea is simple: if I'm already authenticated on one of them, I don't need to sign in on the other.

I've been looking for a solution for a while now, but I would like to ask you: **Do you know or can recommend a package or library to provide SSO to Laravel application?**

Native PHP solutions are also welcome. Thanks!

Comment: have you completed this implementation?

Comment: Yes I did. It's all working fine, however we don't use it on production yet. A new platform is going to be developed and after it is SSO will chain the whole domain family.

Comment: @lessugar Thanks for reply. I was trying to integrate laravel-saml2 in my web application as mentioned in this link: https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2. I've installed and configured as per the steps given in documentation. However if I add a handle method described under usage section of documentation, I'm getting Class 'App\Http\Middleware\SAML2' not found error. Any thought on this?  I think I should post new question. It's difficult to explain everything here.

Comment: @AshokDongare Yep, you definitely should post a new question and provide more info on the error.

Comment: @lesssugar can you please explain a little bit how did you implement this Thanks in advance ,

Answer (score 12):

You can use the SAML standard in order to solve your SSO needs.

Review this github repository that help you implement a SAML service provider:
https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2

If you need to implement a SAML Identity provider you can use simpleSAMLphp and use Lavarel database as authentication source.
https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-idp

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo No, I went with this one: https://github.com/jasny/sso Worked just fine.

Comment: @lesssugar is that on simpleSAML? that doesn't seem to be on it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo It's a custom solution.

Comment: ok thanks. It's the requirement of client to use simple SAML.

Comment: @lesssugar  did you try github.com/jasny/sso i want to do the same but i dont know how to start

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the **[miniorange/saml-laravel-free](https://plugins.miniorange.com/laravel-single-sign-on-sso)** package. It makes things quite simple as it also provides a GUI and also does the whole authentication thing own its own.