# Laravel authentication in multiple instances

Tags: laravel

Since we currently maintain 6 applications that were developed with Laravel, the wish has now arisen that there is a unified login system.

Currently we are working with a database purely for authentication where all applications access it. So the user only has to be created once for all 6 applications.

Now I would like the user to have only one login page and be able to use all applications after authentication.

I would solve the problem with a RSYNC task which synchronizes the cache of the applications. However, I think that there is a better way, so I ask you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a [Single sign-on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on), which has been answered here before some times, but for people who don't know how to call it, it would be pretty hard to find! So here are some links:

[Good single sign-on solution for Laravel by lesssuger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241498/good-single-sign-on-solution-for-laravel)

[single sign on (sso) laravel by Moauya Meghari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532814/single-sign-on-sso-laravel)